# How do I add two numbers and them multiply it with the 3rd number and show the total in a disabled input in a html form with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
This is the html code:
```

the id's are : num1, num2, num3 and the total input is "total"
I want the calc function to be (num1+num2)*num3

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    <label> Tarif Colet</label>
      <input type="num1" onfocus="calculare()" onkeyup="calculare()" onclick="calculare()" onblur="calculare()"  value="0" id="tarifcolet" id="num1"  class="form-control" placeholder="Tarif Colet">
      
    </div>
<div class="col">
      <label>Alte Taxe</label>
      <input type="num2" value="0" onfocus="calculare()" onkeyup="calculare()" onclick="calculare()" onblur="calculare()" id="num2"  class="form-control" placeholder="Alte Taxe">
    </div>
<div class="col">
    <label>Tva</label>
      <input type="percent" name="num3" id="num3" value="19%"  class="form-control" placeholder="TVA">
</div>
    <div class="col">
    <label>Total</label>
      <input type="number" name="total" disabled="disabled" id="total" class="form-control" placeholder="total">
    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far with the function `calculare()`?

Comment: You appear to have input types that are invalid for your inputs ("num1", "num2","percent"). (https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-input-tag.html)

Comment: So do I need to change the inputs? My calculare() function is:  function calculare()
            {
                var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
                var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
                var num3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num3').value);
                
                f.total_colet.value = (parseFloat(num1*1) + parseFloat(num2*1) *  parseFloat(num3*1)).toFixed(2); 
            }

Comment: You should include that function code in your question.  But it does not match the order of operations you specify in the first sentence of your question.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the question but if you are using labels check also how to implement them correctly. Yours currently don't add anything and could be left out completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a value to a disabled input box using the same property you read:

```
function calculare() { 
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value); 
    var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
    var num3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('num3').value);
    document.getElementById("total").value = ((num1 + num2) * num3/100).toFixed(2);
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9s1d2nac/1/

(In the fiddle I fixed the duplicate inputs you've assigned to the first input, leaving only "num1" as the id.)

Comment: Also you could hook calculation to a single `onchange` event instead of a set of `onfocus`, `onkeyup`, `onclick`, `onblur`.

Comment: (Yes, great point @Kitta -- I tried to keep the answer limited to the question in this case.  I also assume the third input should also have an event handler, for instance...)

Answer (score 0):

Use return method.

```
function myFunction(a, b, c) {
 return (a+b)*c;
}
```

And then add in a button onclick event (you can use in other events too).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    <label> Tarif Colet</label>
      <input type="num1" onfocus="calculare()" onkeyup="calculare()" onclick="calculare()" onblur="calculare()"  value="0" id="tarifcolet" id="num1"  class="form-control" placeholder="Tarif Colet">
      
    </div>
<div class="col">
      <label>Alte Taxe</label>
      <input type="num2" value="0" onfocus="calculare()" onkeyup="calculare()" onclick="calculare()" onblur="calculare()" id="num2"  class="form-control" placeholder="Alte Taxe">
    </div>
<div class="col">
    <label>Tva</label>
      <input type="percent" name="num3" id="num3" value="19%"  class="form-control" placeholder="TVA">
</div>
    <div class="col">
    <label>Total</label>
      <input type="number" name="total" disabled="disabled" id="total" class="form-control" placeholder="total">
    </div>
<button type="button" onclick="getValue() ">
```

```
function getValue(){
 var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
var num3 = document.getElementById("num3").value;
var displayResult = document.getElementById("total");
var result = myFunction(num1, num2, num3);

displayResult.value = result;
}
```

I hope this works